# Odoo 13: Override native XML demo data that fails because a constrain in a custom module

Tags: odoo

I have created a custom module in Odoo that includes a new field with a constraint. When I try to install the native demo data, I receive an error message stating that the contraint fails.

Is there some way to solve this?

I added demo data in my module to try overriding native demo record (with id `nativemodule.idofrecord`) so it would pass the constrains.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of my `@api.constrains` method, I added

```
if self._context.get("install_mode"):
    return
```

That's not an optimal solution, but at least it doesn't fail anymore.